# What's a term for a poem with the following qualities?

Tags: terminology, poetry

A poem that

- Has rhyme
- Does not follow a rhythm

I know that if it has both, it's a lyric.
I know if it has neither it's a free verse.
And I know if it has no rhyme, but has rhythm it's a blank verse.

But what about rhyme, but no rhythm?

Comment: Maybe it's *metered verse*?

Comment: @Jim Metered verses don't rhyme? Like, at all?

Comment: I don't know- I'm just guessing wildly. But verse that has rhythm has meter. and *meter* doesn't say anything about rhyme one way or the other.  My reasoning was that if it *had* rhyme it'd be one of the ones you already mentioned. So you might only use *metered* if that's the only thing it had.

Comment: Do you include alliteration with rhyme?

Comment: It's "[blank verse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blank_verse)." You got what it means backwards.

Comment: Yeah, "blank verse".  Though no doubt there are other terms and other classification schemes.

Comment: Scratch that, terms were my fault. Still need a term like this though.

Comment: Been a while, nobody knows?

Answer (score 1):

The form of the poem would be free verse.

Per the Poetry Foundation, [free verse](https://poetryfoundation.org/learn/glossary-terms/free-verse) is a form of poetry with

> Nonmetrical, nonrhyming lines that closely follow the natural rhythms of speech. A regular pattern of sound or rhythm may emerge in free-verse lines, but the poet does not adhere to a metrical plan in their composition. A regular pattern of sound or rhythm may emerge in free-verse lines, but the poet does not adhere to a metrical plan in their composition.

The primary premise of free verse is not the absolute exclusion of poetic devices, such as rhyme or rhythm. The emphasis of free verse is the freedom *from* poetic standardization, which creates the freedom *for* unique poetic expression. Poets may then, independently, include rhyme scheme or rhythm because of the nature of free verse writing. Thus, the poem described in the question lies neatly within the realm of free verse, despite its inclusion of rhyme.

Comment: However, if there is definitely an express rhyme scheme that is maintained for many lines, it may be something else.